# Creating a Custom Cursor, Hiding Default Cursor, and Implementing Multiplayer Features with Username Display and Chatting System in a Website

Tags: web, chat, real-time, mouse-cursor

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a web project and have a few requirements that I'm struggling with. I hope someone can provide guidance or suggestions on how to implement these features effectively.

**Custom Cursor**: I want to give users a unique, custom cursor when they visit my website. I've been experimenting with CSS and JavaScript, but I'm not sure how to achieve this seamlessly.

**Hiding Default Cursor**: I also want to hide the default cursor to create a more immersive user experience. What's the best way to accomplish this while ensuring cross-browser compatibility?

**Multiplayer Functionality**: I aim to make my website multiplayer-friendly, allowing multiple users to interact with it simultaneously. I'd appreciate advice on the architecture or technologies (e.g., WebSockets) to use for real-time synchronization.

**Username Display**: To enhance user interaction, I'd like to display each user's username near their cursor, preferably in the bottom-right corner. How can I dynamically attach this information to their cursor in real-time?

**Chatting System**: Finally, I want to implement a chatting system that enables users to communicate with each other while using the website. What tools or libraries are suitable for this task, and how can I integrate them smoothly into my project?

I'm open to code samples, tutorials, or any pointers that can help me achieve these goals. Thank you for your assistance!